# Application to reproduce Mac OS X full screen mode?

Tags: xubuntu, desktop-environments, workspaces, macosx, maximized

I am currently running Xubuntu 13.04, but this would also be cool on Stock Ubuntu.

I am a big fan of the way full screen works in Mac OS X, and would like to reproduce the effect on Linux with workspaces. I like how a maximized application never covers up windows.

My Question is, is there a program or script that helps with the following

1. Move windows to their own workspace when they are maximized
2. Allow only one maximized window in a workspace
3. Move the window back out of the workspace when it is restored
4. Or replicates the Mac OS X feature in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try pressing <kbd>F11</kbd>?

Usually, most applications will utilize the Full Screen mode using <kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

Comment: This explains how you go into full screen mode. But doesn't answer how the application is moved to its own workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Using LXDE desktop environment as I recommended. It has all of your necessary features list 100%. Or any Window Managers...

Specify for only full-size / full-screen applications thing, just using display manager of LX, that full package name is **lxdm**. Then install **lxpanel** package, and using **lxhotkey-core** package.

All features of LXDE desktop environment, as your wanted:
[image of lxhotkey-core on LXDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRSuF.png)